# Does this sentence make sense with Do?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

> I will do play the football.

Does this sentence above make sense? Then, what is the difference between

- I will play the football.

... and:

- I will do play the football.

Answer (score 1):

No, this sentence does not make sense. [Do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) (inserting the word do as an auxiliary verb) only occurs in the present tense (*I do play football*) and the simple past (*I did play football*), when there is no other auxiliary verb. In this case, *will* is the auxiliary verb, and so *do* cannot also be used.

When not used in a question or a negative sentence, the purpose of inserting the word *do* is to add emphasis to the veracity/truthfulness of the statement. This can be done with the simple future tense in speech by simply adding stress to the word will (I *will* play football).

Note: no article is used when using *play* with a sport: *play football* not *play the football*.

Comment: +1 We also sometimes use do with tenseless constructions such as imperatives: "Don't be late!" for example.